# Time Machine says "Waiting to complete first backup"

Tags: backup, time-machine

I followed this guide to create a time machine remote server:
https://www.howtogeek.com/276468/how-to-use-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-networked-time-machine-drive-for-your-mac/

It seemed to work at first, it started to upload the backup file but at the very end it showed a message that said "waiting to complete first backup" and that happens every time I try to back up.

I looked through the console and it says it has problems with finding and unmounting the disk, which is confusing since it connects and uploads correctly.

[image]

Comment: I couldn't figure out what was wrong but I switched from netatalk to samba and it now works just fine.